# unity、C#にて、キーボードの矢印のキーによる操作をボタン操作に切り替えたい

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity2d

下記のようなコードで、矢印キーでオブジェクトを動かせる状態になっています
これを、上、下、右、左それぞれのボタンで動かせるようにしたいのですが、どのようにコードを編集すればいいのかいまいちわかりません
教えてください

```
public class OnKeyPress_Move : MonoBehaviour
{
  public float speed = 2; 

  float vx = 0;
  float vy = 0;

  void Update()
  {
    vx = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * speed;
    vy = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * speed;
  }
  private void FixedUpdate()
  {
    this.tranform.Translate(vx / 50, vy / 50, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: 少し違うかもしれませんが、何かこれらの記事が参考になるかも。[\[Unity\]\[C# Script\]「新しい」INPUT SYSTEMによるコントローラの統合(PC版)(仮公開)](https://zenn.dev/k1togami/articles/eea2cd01d4199c), [Unityの新入力システム・Input Systemを使おう](https://forpro.unity3d.jp/unity_pro_tips/2021/05/20/1957/), [Unityの新しい入力システムInputSystemを使ってみる](https://gametukurikata.com/basic/inputsystem)

Comment: できれば[Input.GetButton]などを使って書き換えたいです

Comment: その辺の関数に相当する物が`Keyboard.current.キー.wasPressedThisFrame`とか`Gamepad.current.ボタン.wasPressedThisFrame`に変わった風な感じで説明されているようですが。[【Unity】Input Systemの基本的な使い方](https://gamedev65535.com/entry/unity_inputsystem_howtouse/) 古いAPIのままならこちらかも。[UnityのInputで入力を扱う](https://qiita.com/yando/items/c406690c9ad87ecfc8e5)

Comment: 「上、下、右、左それぞれのボタン」というのがどれか分からないですが、ハードウェアとの対比とかカスタマイズみたいなものはこれらの記事が参考になるかも。[Unityでゲームパッドからの入力したいからまとめてみる(XBox One Controller)](https://hakonebox.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/04/15/125152), [UnityのUIでゲームパッドとキー操作でアイコンを動かしボタン操作を行う](https://gametukurikata.com/ui/gamepaduiwindow), [UnityでXboxコントローラの3Dスティックではなく十字キーで移動させる場合](https://portaltan.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/05/18/104329), [【Unity】uGUIをキーボードやゲームパッドに対応させる方法](https://moon-bear.com/2020/05/25/ugui-gamepad/)

Comment: コメントくれた方ありがとうございます　ボタンというのはクリックして動作する方です　スマホで動かせるようにしたいです　しかし、私のunityで現在進行中のプロジェクトで他にもいろいろ不具合が生じており、その問題の解決に先にとりかかっているので、この質問の件に関しては解決するのにまだ時間がかかりそうです

Comment: GUIでも使いたいとかだとこれらの記事でしょうか。[How to make a UI button emulate a keyboard key](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1480651/how-to-make-a-ui-button-emulate-a-keyboard-key.html), [Is it possible to simulate a keypress/input in code?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/588786/is-it-possible-to-simulate-a-keypressinput-in-code.html), [How to simulate a key press on button click - Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48930193/9014308), [UIのボタンを押したら特定のキーボードを押したことにしたい](https://teratail.com/questions/314519)

Comment: 返信が遅れてすいませんでした。こちらの記事を参考にしたらうまく行きました。https://qiita.com/netty/items/66284cbb2bb1cd42a486

Answer (score 0):

Button の事を言っているのであれば、コードは大幅に変える必要があります。
Button に EventTrigger コンポーネントをアタッチし、押している間は移動するようにしなければなりません。（OnClick でやってもダメ）

パッケージ: [82280.unitypackage](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nvomscebfqzdyv5/82280.unitypackage?dl=1)

パッケージに含むコードは以下だけです。

```cs
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class ButtonMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float _speed = 3f;
    Rigidbody2D _rb = default;

    void Start()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    public void Move(string dir)
    {
        Vector2 velo = Vector2.zero;

        switch (dir)
        {
            case "Right":
                velo = Vector2.right;
                break;
            case "Left":
                velo = Vector2.left;
                break;
            case "Up":
                velo = Vector2.up;
                break;
            case "Down":
                velo = Vector2.down;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        _rb.velocity = _speed * velo;
    }
}
```